# How to fixed or sort google translate language options in custom order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I am using google translate API to translate my page and have some language options like en,de,fr,it So, google **shows all languages in alphabetical order in the dropdown**, but I need to **show this in order the way it is write-in function. or in the custom order whatever order we like to give

```
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'en,de,fr,it' }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
```

It is **showing now** - `English, French, German, Italy` but I need to show this in `German, English, French, Italy`

Comment: Did you tried 'de,en,fr,it' instead of 'en,de,fr,it' ?

Comment: @SKJ yes I have tried it always shows by sorting them in alphabetical order.

Comment: Can you post the generated html in your div plz ?